# Show if a sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $Tf_n=Tf_n'$ converges to $g\in C[0,1]$, then we have $f\in D$ and $Tf = g$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider $C[0,1]$, the vector space of all continuous complex valued functions on $[0,1]$ with supremum norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.

Let $D \subset C[0,1]$ be the set such that derivative $f'(x)$ exists and continuous on $[0,1]$.

Let $T:D \rightarrow C[0,1]$ be an linear operator defined by $Tf=f'$.

This linear operator is not bounded, because there is no constant $M$ such that $\|T(f)\| \le M\|f\|$ for all $f \in D$.

---

Show that the linear unbounded operator $T$ is closed in the sense that: if a sequence $(f_n)\in D$ converges to $f\in C[0,1]$ such that the sequence $Tf_n$ converges to $g\in C[0,1]$, then we have $f\in D$ and $Tf = g$.

Comment: What problem did you encountered in proving this?

Comment: @John Showing $D$ is either complete or closed and hence the last statement $Tf=g$ if this is the right path..

Comment: $D$ is neither complete nor closed.  So you cannot use that approach.  See what you can get out of $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt.$